# Newbie question: find CURL like functionality in Lisp

Tags: lisp, package

I am a newbie in lisp trying to write a program to download a page content from the internet. I'm pretty sure that there should be such functionality in some of the packages. What package is suited best for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try CL-Curl: http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-curl